# After Ubuntu update display size is 7" and it loads a Mobile version of Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, display, resolution

Using Ubuntu 13.10 after the latest update I restarted. Now there is no mouse cursor, the screen resolution has changed to 1920x1080 and the text is unnecessarily huge. I managed to get to the display settings and found that Ubuntu falsely believes the screen is 7" when actually it's connected via. HDMI to a 32" TV.

Screenshot:

[image]

The graphics card is an ATi Radeon 5450 using proprietary "fglrx-updates" driver. I have tried using xorg, but it's even worse with the same issues only a max resolution of 1024x768.

Update:
Every time the desktop loads I get a system problem detected error and asks if I want to report it. There's also some other strange problems like in totem if it's full-screen the bar which pops up at the bottom no longer appears on mouse movement and instead the screen just flickers.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, this problem does not appear to be related to the 13.10 update.

After loading the GRUB menu by holding shift when booting up and pressing 'e' on the main Ubuntu entry, I discovered a sequence of references to "msdos".

The solution therefore is to return the GRUB entry to it's default state.

To conclude, this issue appears to be caused by dual boot with Windows and not with Ubuntu 13.10 as previously stated.